# Can a Kusari-gama or Kyoketsu-shoge be used as a Pact Weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, warlock

I was wanting to create a pact of the blade warlock for D&D 5e. I had a sort of [*Mortal Kombat* Scorpion](http://mortalkombat.wikia.com/wiki/Scorpion) type of idea. I'm not in a group right now, but I was wondering...

**Is there a rule about rather or not someone can use a chain weapon as a pact weapon or is it strictly a Dungeon Master's prerogative?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76458/discussion-on-question-by-mumbles-dureausou-can-a-kusari-gama-or-kyoketsu-shoge).

Comment: On a different topic, are you referencing [this Imgur page](https://imgur.com/a/Lyfcb) directly? Keep in-mind that that is a fan-made sequence, and those weapons are entirely homebrewed, so you would have to talk to your GM about them in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Nothing prohibits having a Chain Weapon as a Pact Weapon...

...Provided that weapon is a Melee weapon. The relevant feature of the [Pact of the Blade](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Warlock#toc_9) Pact Boon states:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand. You can choose the form that this **melee weapon** takes each time you create it. You are proficient with it while you wield it. This weapon counts as magical for the purpose of overcoming Resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage.

(Emphasis mine)

Specifically, the *created* weapon has to be a melee weapon. So, any weapon that qualified as Melee would be viable, so long as your GM allowed it. You are also even proficient in it while you have it, which is a great way to get a Martial Weapon without needing proficiency in Martial Weapons.

It is also important to note that, even if the GM rules these as Ranged weapons, any Magical Weapon can be bound to you as per the second feature of Pact of the Blade:

> You can transform one Magic Weapon into your pact weapon by performing a Special ritual while you hold the weapon. You perform the ritual over the course of 1 hour, which can be done during a Short Rest. You can then dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter. You can’t affect an artifact or a sentient weapon in this way. The weapon ceases being your pact weapon if you die, if you perform the 1-hour ritual on a different weapon, or if you use a 1-hour ritual to break your bond to it. The weapon appears at your feet if it is in the extradimensional space when the bond breaks.

Thus, even if it was decided that a chain weapon like this was a Ranged weapon, if your GM created a magical variant of it and you got ahold of it, you would be allowed to bind it to yourself as your pact weapon.

Comment: Note that there are no Exotic Weapons or Exotic Weapon proficiency in 5e.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Good Point. They would probably count as Martial Weapons, then, since they "require more training to use."

Comment: @SeraphsWrath Except a nunchaku can literally be a club according to the Player's Handbook. (Even though I can tell you from experience, it is MUCH more difficult to wield a nunchaku effectively than a club). Not that I think these should be simple weapons, just that the justification is more complex

Comment: @DavidCoffron: I think that nunchaku were declared to be clubs so that Monks could use them; if I were to map them to any standard 5e weapon, it would be the flail, but I don't think Monks are proficient with it.

Comment: @sharur Perhaps "monk weapon variant" should be its own pseudo-category as the damage die changes with levels (an experience monk will do more damage, perhaps comparable to a flail or more, while a new monk just uses like a club)

Answer (score 10):

Those weapons are not currently in the game, as they are not listed as weapon section of the 5e PHB, their existence and stats would fall to the DM. Most DMs wouldn't bat an eye of flavoring the whip or maul, without changing stats.  However, mechanical changes would be harder to convince a DM to do, because they would need to be balanced and playtested.  The list of weapons in the game can be found on page 149 of the PHB.

That said, if the DM allowed them to exist as melee weapons, your Warlock would be allowed to have them as their pact weapon.

Answer (score 5):

## Re-flavoring Weapons

While those weapons are not currently in the game (and therefore not valid for Pact of the Blade), there is an entry under the Martial Arts feature of Monk that sheds some light on how weapons like those could be implemented:

> Certain monasteries use specialized forms of monk weapons. For example, you might use a club that is two lengths of wood connected by a short chain (called a nunchaku) or a sickle with a shorter, straighter blade (called a kama).
>
> [Player's Handbook p. 78]

This sets a precedent that making small aesthetic changes to existing weapons is fine; you just treat the weapon as its Player's Handbook equivalent.

### What weapons to use?

A **Kusari-gama** can serve the same function as a **Glaive**, so your DM could treat it as a glaive (and the Polearm Master feat would let you use the blunt end as a bonus action in the same manner that the kusari-gama is typically wielded). Just never make an attack with the bladed end at reach and you've got it (you are always allowed to limit your character's decisions for flavor reasons).

A **Kyoketsu-shoge** is a very distinct fighting style, so an exact parallel is difficult. The best your DM could get is the **Pike**, again using the bladed end only within 5 feet. Just like with the kusari-gama, the Polearm Master feat will be necessary to use the ring-end at reach (as a bonus action).

While not a typical technique with these weapons, throwing the blade of either and pulling back on the chain to return it to your hand could justify your reach attacks with them (since they have that capability as re-skins of the pike or glaive).

### Can I summon it?

If your DM allows small changes to the fundamental weapon options for this purpose *or has homebrewed these weapons*, you can summon them with Pact of the Blade as long as they are melee weapons.

> You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it.

Comment: Remember, though, that Homebrewing is allowed on this site. I think the OP is referencing [this](https://imgur.com/a/Lyfcb) specifically (note this is fan-made).

Comment: @SeraphsWrath The OP never stated that he is using that source. It is a senseless assumption (especially since "chain weapon" isn't a term on that page)

Comment: Regardless, using homebrewed equipment is a valid play-style. If the GM in that campaign is allowing that (and I have asked that question in the comments), then one can certainly use them so long as an agreement is reached.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath I added a note about homebrewed weapons in the last section

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Since other answers have addressed
 "Are there chain weapons in D&D 5e?"

and "If there was a melee chain weapon available, could I use it as a pact weapon?",

I frame challenge that your core problem is actually: **"How can I play a Warlock kind of like Scorpion, from Mortal Kombat?"**)</sup>

#### Eldritch Blast is very versatile (and can pull targets)

At second level, you get access to invocations. One of them (Grasp of Hadar) allows you to pull enemies 10 feet closer to you (*"GET OVER HERE!"*).

> Grasp of Hadar (Xanathar's Guide to Everything) 
> Prerequisite: eldritch blast cantrip
> Once on each of your turns when you hit a creature with your eldritch blast, you can move that creature in a straight line 10 feet closer to you.

Talk to your DM to reskin your bolt of force energy as a bolt of *creepy-hell-kunai-on-a-rope* energy.

With *Misty Step* and *Hellish Rebuke*, you've got plenty of Fatality-Flavored Fun.

Comment: No my true question was on my ability to be able to use the chain weapon at all as a pact weapon, but i do like your ideas and plan to use. Thank you and thank you all!